# Random Array generator in c #

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I need to create an *array* with a specific number of rows and columns based on user input.

**So far I have :**

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of rows: ");
int rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of columns: ");
int cols = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] board = new int[rows, cols];
```

How do I take this information and then make a *random* list that goes up based on the entered information?
so it looks like this,
rows=2 colums =3

1  2  3

4  5  6

Comment: So do you want *random* data or the deterministic data at the end of your question?

Answer (score 1):

The program you want has two steps, but can be achieved in one. First create the 2d array, then set the value for each grid index. This can be achieved in one method.
First declare your new grid and counter. Then loop through every column in every row and set the value of each index as the counter + 1. This will count as the loop goes through ever position. For clarity here's an image of what this method would look like, having it take the number of rows and columns as a parameter.

```
void CreateGrid(int rows, int cols)
        {
            int[,] Grid = new int[cols, rows];
            //create the grid

            int counter = 0;
            //Intailized the counter

            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                //loops through every column
                Console.WriteLine("");
                //Creates a newline to write the columns on.
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    //Gos through every column.
                    Grid[j, i] = counter++;
                    //Sets the current grid position 
                    //as the current counter number.
                    Console.Write(" " + Grid[j, i]);
                   //Writes that grid number in the current line
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two loops for each row and column.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of rows: ");
        int rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of columns: ");
        int cols = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] board = new int[rows, cols];

        var r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {                    
                board[i, j] = r.Next(0, 10);
                Console.Write(board[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Then it gives an output like this:

[image]

Comment: It needs to go in order tho, like 1,2,3,4,5... ect. not sure how to get it to count up

Comment: Move the `var r = new Random()` out of the loop. You should better not create multiple random object as these will likely produce the same random numbers. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0#avoiding-multiple-instantiations)

Comment: Better yet, make sure `Random` is initialized only once, preferably as a static field.

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory class that contains all the methods to generate array structures.

```
public static class Factory
{
    static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    public static int[] CreateRandomArray(int size, int minValue, int maxValue)
        => CreateRandomArray(rng, size, minValue, maxValue);

    public static int[] CreateRandomArray(this Random rng, int size, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        var array = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rng.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static int[,] CreateRandomArray2(int rows, int cols, int minValue, int maxValue) 
        => CreateRandomArray2(rng, rows, cols, minValue, maxValue);

    public static int[,] CreateRandomArray2(this Random rng, int rows, int cols, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        var matrix = new int[rows, cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = rng.Next(minValue, maxValue);
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
    public static double[] CreateRandomVector(int size, double minValue, double maxValue)
        => CreateRandomVector(rng, size, minValue, maxValue);

    public static double[] CreateRandomVector(this Random rng, int size, double minValue, double maxValue)
    {
        var array = new double[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = minValue + (maxValue-minValue) * rng.NextDouble();
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static double[,] CreateRandomMatrix(int rows, int cols, double minValue, double maxValue)
        => CreateRandomMatrix(rng, rows, cols, minValue, maxValue);

    public static double[,] CreateRandomMatrix(this Random rng, int rows, int cols, double minValue, double maxValue)
    {
        var matrix = new double[rows, cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = minValue + (maxValue-minValue) * rng.NextDouble();
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

To be used like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] A = Factory.CreateRandomArray2(rows: 2, cols: 3, minValue: 0, maxValue: 9);
        double[] b = Factory.CreateRandomVector(size: 9, minValue: -1.0, maxValue: 1.0);
    }
}
```

or as an extension method to an existing random number generator `Random`

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Random random = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] A = random.CreateRandomArray2(rows: 2, cols: 3, minValue: 0, maxValue: 9);
        double[] b = random.CreateRandomVector(size: 9, minValue: -1.0, maxValue: 1.0);
    }
}
```